# как скрыть/показать Fragment

Tags: java, android

Не могу реализовать скрыть/показать фрагмент, прочитал что играться с visibility не лучший вариант, что это всё делается проще, через fragmentManager(), но у меня не получается, ошибки никакой не выдает.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
}
```

Ну и в главном  окне я просто хочу его скрыть кнопкой.

```
public class Logistic extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
Fragment1 fragment1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logistic_empty);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_test_logistic);
    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                    .hide(fragment1)
                    .commit();
        }
    });


}
```

Но вообще ничего не происходит.

вот xml фрагмента

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#77ff0000"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4" />
```

[image: не работает тоже]

Comment: Фрагмент находиться в контейнере?

Comment: Обновил тело письма, вроде бы да, но насколько правильно я это только что сделал, не знаю.

Comment: Из Вашего кода видно, что вы создаете фрагмент и больше ничего с ним не делаете. Вы не добавили его в контейнер и потом пытаетесь его скрыть.

Comment: Выглядит примерно так  
 ragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    fragment1, FIRST_FRAG_TAG).commit(); Если надо добавлять только при первом запуске оберните в         if (savedInstanceState == null) {}

Comment: "вот xml фрагмента" - фрагмента или Активити? т.к. если фрагмента то у вас в самом фрагменте находиться контейнер куда Вы собираетесь этот фрагмент засунуть ну или у Вас несколько уровней вложенности (в фрагменте другой фрагмент)

Comment: это иксмл фрагмента, значит можно контейнер убрать?Я не совсем понимаю логику работы пока что с фрагментами. он у меня норм открывается и без контейнера в MainActivity, но вот обратиться я к нему не могу и поменять что то

Comment: Фрагменты можно добавлять динамически (один контейнер и в нем добавлять, менять, удалять и т.д. фрагменты) или статически (в xml указываете фрагмент и он сразу добавляется). Вся прелесть фрагментов как раз в динамической работе, хотя если нет необходимости менять фрагменты, логичней использовать статический фрагмент. Есть много ресурсов где про это рассказывают и на ютюбе есть куча уроков.

Comment: ок, особенности я позже буду узнавать. но сейчас я опять обновил тело письма , и предложенный вами код не работает

Comment: ну как минимум Вам подчеркивает FIRST_FRAG_TAG - это константа которую на создать. Во вторых это надо делать не при клике, а выше в onCreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем фрагмент в контейнер при первом запуске

```
private final static String FIRST_FRAG_TAG = "f1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                new Fragment1(), FIRST_FRAG_TAG).commit();
    }
```

По клику скрываем фрагмент

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment1 firstFragment = (Fragment1) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FIRST_FRAG_TAG);
    if (firstFragment != null && firstFragment.isVisible()) {
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
       .hide(firstFragment)
       .commit();
    }
});
```

В самом фрагменте правильно создаем View

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
    return myView;
}
```

Это при условии что контейнер находиться не в разметке самого Fragment1

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо один раз создать фрагмент, а не при каждом вызове создавать новый, то вы можете
объявить глобально тэги для фрагментов, например
`val Fragment1 = "fragment1"` и далее по аналогии

в onCreate :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            pushFragments(FRAGMENT1, FirstFragment())
            pushFragments(FRAGMENT2, SecondFragment())
        }
```

Создайте функцию

```
 fun pushFragments(tag: String, fragment: Fragment) {
        val manager = supportFragmentManager
        val ft = manager.beginTransaction()

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        }

        val fragmentFirst = manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT1)
        val fragmentSecond = manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT2)

        // Hide all Fragment
        if (fragmentFirst != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentFirst)
        }
        if (fragmentSecond != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentSecond)
        }

        // Show  current Fragment
        if (tag === FRAGMENT1) {
            if (fragmentFirst != null) {
                ft.show(fragmentFirst)
            }
        }
        if (tag === FRAGMENT2) {
            if (fragmentSecond != null) {
                ft.show(fragmentSecond)
            }
        }

        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
```

чтобы вызвать и отобразить фрагмент необходимо

```
pushFragments(FRAGMENT1, FirstFragment())
```